# curving a 3 dimentional curved object

Tags: bevel

I have a curved 3 dimentional object and I am trying to add a bevel/curve to one of the corners on each side, and the leading edge.  I can play around with the edges and vertices and get the curve I want however to curve it enough, it creats a flat plane.  I have attached a few images to show you what I mean and the original file.
[image: actual]
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm a bit of a noob.

Cheers,
Dru.[image: blendercurve]

Comment: What happens when you try to use the bevel tool (Ctrl-B) after selecting the relevant edge loop in Edit Mode?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.

due to the initial curve in the piece, there are many edge loops and so using bevel doesn't work.  Are you perhaps suggesting that I use a flat piece, create the curves and then bend the piece, that might work...

Comment: To be honest, I no longer believe I understand your situation sufficiently. It might be a good idea to include more pictures and modify them with visual aids and descriptions.

Comment: Thanks again for your help anyway.  I don't think I fully understand it myself.  You can see in the real life picture what I am basically trying to emulate.  The difficulty is in having two bevels with a bend, which do you do first so that it is possible.  I need to rethink this and I'll be back once I have more questions.

Again, thanks for replying mate.

Comment: Why not just add a subdivision surface modifier to the object, without beveling it at all? A one step means of rounding the entire shape to make it look mostly like the chair arm? You can even add creases to subdivision surfaces, should you want the bottom surface to have less roundness at the edge than the top surface.